# How to display a message when opening HTA file with VBS

Tags: cmd, vbscript, wsh, hta

I have VBS file with the only line

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "cmd /c start mshta.exe %cd%/app.hta",0,True
```

When I click this VBS file, there is a delay before the HTA file is opened, so I need to display some message during that time and hide it when HTA file is opened. It will be better if I would be able to stylize the window with the message.

How can I do it?

Comment: VBScript doesn't really provide means for parallel execution, even though there are workarounds for some scenarios. You could use the [`Popup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f.aspx) method, but that's just based on a timer, so it won't react to whether the HTA is started or not. But why do you need the VBScript in the first place? You could just launch the HTA directly.

Comment: This HTA file is destined for different users and I noticed I can't open it directly on some computers without right-clicking, the "Open with..." command and finding mshta.exe inside of the Windows folder. So I need the file is being opened without these additional actions and VBS is the only way I've found at the moment.

Comment: I would recommend fixing the configuration on those computers where directly launching a HTA doesn't work.

Comment: But that also mean additional actions I don't want to force users to do. It's better to try the Popup method

Comment: I don't think you should cater to users with broken configurations, but of course that's for you to decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of a message with the `Popup` method:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Popup "Please wait...", 1, "Window tile"
```

`1` is seconds to wait

Answer (score 1):

This will speed up starting the program. See no starting a program called `cmd` for no real purpose. No calling `cmd`'s `Start` which starts program in unusual ways and slow by nature. Specifing it's path means it doesn't need to be searched for.

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\windows\system32\mshta.exe ""%cd%\app.hta""",0,True
```